# Get values from array of arrays using push

Tags: javascript

I want to get values from an array of arrays, and I'm having difficulties doing it.
I have the following:

```
var id = 1; //value I want to use for the search 
var _restrictions = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [5, 1], [1, 6]]; //arrays that I want to check
var arrVal = [];
```

By using the id, I want to retrieve all of the values, inside the arrays, where the id exits and store them in the array "arrVal".

For example:

```
_restrictions = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [5, 1], [1, 6]];
//arrVal will be: [2, 5, 6], because the id existing inside the arrays [1,2], 
//[5,1] and [1,6]
```

The "_restrictions" array is a array of arrays that contain restrictions. They are independent values (the first one isn't the index or id).
How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to get the first index of all the nested arrays?

Comment: You'll have to explain exactly what [1,2] and [2,4] mean. Which of the two numbers is the id? The first I assume? So are you trying to get the values `[ 2, 6 ]` ? Since _restrictions contains two arrays where the first number equals the id 1? Or do you want `[ [1,2], [5,1], [1,6] ]`, since all 3 of those arrays contain the number 1?

Comment: @Abrar No, the only thing I have is the code I've insert here. Do you have any clue how to do it?

Comment: So, for this example, arrVal should have [[1,2], [5,1], [1,6]] ??

Comment: Well if you want the first index then you can do this: ```var arrVal = _restrictions.map((item) => {
  return item[id]
});```

Comment: In case you are trying to get the sub arrays which have `id` in them: ```var arrVal = _restrictions.filter((item) => {
  return item.includes(id)
});```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective is for others to help you fix your code. Also show expected results

Comment: @Araújo take a look at my answer. Updated it with new code.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated code after the question is edited.

The question lacks a bit of clarity. I am assuming you want to filter the sub-arrays which have `id` in them i.e. contains the value `1`.

```
let id = 1; //value I want to use for the search 
let _restrictions = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [5, 1], [1, 6]];

let arrVal = _restrictions.filter((item) => {
        return item.includes(id);
});

let new_array = arrVal.concat.apply([], arrVal).filter(x => x !== id);

console.log(new_array);
// [2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Exactly! All I want are the values, inside the sub-arrays, that have the id (value 1) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that will work for any size of nested array. It returns an flattened array of all values not including the id.

```js
var id = 1; 
var _restrictions = [[1, 2, 9], [2, 4], [5, 1], [1, 6]];

var arrVal = _restrictions.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Find the index of the id in each nested array
  const i = c.findIndex(arr => arr === id);

  // If it exists, splice it out and add it
  // to the accumulator array
  if (i > -1) {
    c.splice(i, 1);
    acc.push(...c);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arrVal);
```